# App is crashing when trying to check radio button status

Tags: java, android

I have two radio button in my app Yes and No.So whenever user select Yes then I want to show bottom sheet dialog but app is crashing whenever it launches.

It is showing error below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.CharSequence android.widget.TextView.getText()' on a null object reference
```

Below is my code:

```
public class Signup extends AppCompatActivity {

RadioButton radioButton;
RadioGroup radioGroup;
BottomSheetDialog bottomSheetDialog;
int selectedID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    
    radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    
    selectedID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    radioButton = findViewById(selectedID);

      if(radioButton.getText().toString().equals("Yes")){

         bottomSheetDialog = new BottomSheetDialog(Signup.this);
         bottomSheetDialog.setContentView(R.layout.bottom_file_type);
         bottomSheetDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
         bottomSheetDialog.show();
    }


   }
}
```

Comment: No I want to check whether yes button is clicked and based on that show bottom sheet dialog.

Comment: Open the link, read the answer, understand what a NPE is, fix it and then maybe come back and ask another question.

Comment: I presume the `if` statement is running before any `RadioButton` is selected and, as such, the line `radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` returns `0`. No `RadioButton` exists with that ID so `findViewById(selectedID)` returns `null`. Since your `radioButton` is `null`, that's the error you receive. 
I would suggest listening for an `OnCheckedChangeListener` listener to the `radioGroup` and putting your `if` statement there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
radioGroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
radioGroup.getChildAt(0).setChecked(true);
selectedID = radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
```

This selects the first item in the group during initialization.

And I suggest to change this:

```
// if(radioButton.getText().toString().equals("Yes"))
if(selectedID == R.id.radioButtonYes)
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like your `radioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId()` call isn't returning valid id of checked `RadioButton` (probably nothing is checked at start), so `findViewById(selectedID);` return `null`. further you are trying to `radioButton.getText()` on `null` object and this is `NullPointerException`

probably fastest way to fix is to add `android:checked="true"` to one of `RadioButton`s declared in your `activity_signup` XML file

Comment: Thanks bro, got it have not selected any radio button.